# How to dynamically refer to the specific data frame and change its cells

Tags: r

I have two data frames soft.filter(n) and softq(n) where n = 1:59. N determines the dimensionality (number of rows in df), so that number of rows is equal to some number plus n (number of columns is 2).

The idea is to refer to every of 59 df soft.filter(n), calculate geometric average of 3 cells and assign it to the first cell of softq(n) and so on.

I tried something like this:

```
for (m in 1:59) {
      for(j in 1:2) { 
            for (i in 2:dim(get(paste0("softq",m)))[1]) {

                  assign(get(paste0("softq", m))[i,j], qmean(get(paste0("soft.filter",m))[(i*3-2),j],get(paste0("soft.filter",m))[(i*3-1),j],get(paste0("soft.filter",m))[(i*3),j]))
            }

      }
}
```

But it cannot refer to a specific cell in softq(n) df. So I want to assing the value caltulated with the help of qmean function to softq(m)[i,j].

Appreciate your response.